# How to extend my interface type to support a function/method call?

Tags: typescript

I want to modify this interface to support a method call, is that possible in typescript?

```
export interface Product {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   sku: string,
   locations: Array<Location>
}
```

I want to add a function like to check if a particular location exists.

```
function has_locations(location_ids: Array<string>) {
  return ......
}
```

So I currently have this `Product` interface as a parameter to a lot of functions in my applications, so curious as to what options I have to modify the interface.

Comment: • What's `Location`? Is that the native JS one or something private? Please [edit] to make this a [mre] we can play with in our IDEs without having issues you're not having. • You want to add the function where exactly? You can use declaration merging to add a method to `Product` but I don't know if that's what you want because it's not clear to me from this code how you want to use it.

Comment: (See prev comments) Interfaces don't exist at runtime, so if you want behavior to change you'll need to write some JavaScript. Where do you actually have values of type `Location`? That's where you'd need to add a method if you want one (although I don't know if I see the appeal; why would `obj.hasLocations()` be preferable to `hasLocations(obj)`, especially if the former would require you to touch every `obj` in existence)? If `Product` were a class you could do this easily, but since it's an interface can you show us where `Product` values get made?

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces don't perform method call, but you can declare a method call in one:

```
export interface Product {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   sku: string,
   locations: Array<Location>
   has_locations(locations_id: Array<string>): boolean // like this
}
```

You can change the type from `boolean` to whatever type you which to return.

---

In case you don't want to modify the existing interface, you can do:

```
export interface Product {
   id: string,
   name: string,
   sku: string,
   locations: Array<Location>
   
}

export interface ProductWithFunc extends Product {
    has_locations(locations_id: Array<string>): boolean
}
```

Comment: can I also somehow create an extension method on the Product interface?  That way I don't even have to modify the existing interface...